# PHP & SQL Query Efficieny for * or Specific Columns

Tags: php, sql, oracle, performance

I have an Oracle database view in which I have access to 17 columns and approximately 15k rows (this grows at a rate of about 700 rows per year). I only need to use 10 of the columns. At the moment I am searching for ways to make my query more efficient since my app load about 7.5k of the entries at first. I know I could only load lets say 1k entries and that would be a way to speed up the loading process; however, the users often need to query through more than the 1k entries loaded initially, and I do not want to make them wait through a second loading of data into the app.

So I guess my main question is that when I query the Oracle view should I query and just do a * query on the database or select specific columns? I know that best practices state only query the columns you need; however, I am looking at this from a performance standpoint and would I see a significant performance increase by only querying the 10 specific columns I need rather than a * query on the view?

Comment: Can you provide code samples? That would make it much easier for those of us who are visual thinkers. I can't think of any reason why being more specific would make the query less performant...

Comment: I'm not an expert but think of it this way: every character is a about 2-3 bytes. Adds up to quite a bit rapidly doesn't it? It's not the same amount as downloading images say, but (average) 64 bytes x 17 x 15k. Adds up! A way to calculate it would be to do a query for EVERYTHING and add 1 for every ASCII number eg: space=042

Comment: There are probably better ways to improve the performance than by reducing the number of columns -- unless the columns are very wide.  However, reducing the number shouldn't hurt performance.

Comment: The only way to know what sort of speedup you'd have is to try it and see.  There is no general rule about what sort of improvement you'll see.  However, I can say that there's no way that specifying columns instead of * will slow things down.

Answer (score 2):

As @AndyLester says, the only way to know for sure is to try it out and see.  There are reasons to expect that specifying the actual set of columns you need will be faster.  The question is whether the difference will be "significant" which is something only you can tell us.

There are a few reasons to expect performance improvements

1. Specifying the actual set of columns decreases the amount of data that has to be transmitted over the network and decreases the amount of memory that is consumed on the client.  Whether this is significant or not depends on the relative size of the columns that you're selecting vs. the columns you're excluding.  If you only need a bunch of `varchar2(10)` columns and the columns that you don't need include some `varchar2(1000)` columns, you might be eliminating the vast majority of your network traffic and of the RAM consumed on the client.  If you're only excluding a few `char(1)` columns while you're selecting a bunch of `clob` columns, the reduction may be trivial.
2. Specifying the actual set of columns can produce a more efficient plan.  Depending on the Oracle version, the view definition, and the definition of the underlying tables it's possible that some of the joins can be eliminated when you're selecting a subset of columns.  This, in turn, can produce a much more efficient plan.
3. Specifying the actual set of columns means that your application's performance is much less likely to change if additional columns are added to the view.  Your code won't suddenly start pulling that new data over the network into memory structures on the client.  It may not need to join in the additional tables that might be referenced.

Since there is no downside to specifying the column list, I'd strongly suggest doing so regardless of the size of the performance improvement.  If you're really concerned about performance, however, it's likely that you'd want to be looking at performance more holistically (examining what is actually taking time in your process, for example).

Comment: Along with this answer, I'd say it's better to specify columns so you know exactly what columns will be returned to your code. This is especially true if you reference the columns by their index in the row. This is more dependent on how you handle your data access logic, though.